# drupal : how to show two nodes in one page

Tags: php, drupal

how to show two nodes in one page ?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several ways:

- Views - set filters or arguments to show 2 nodes;
- Block - show other node in blocks via special modules (like node as block) or programmatically call node_view;
- Custom node theming - programmatically call node_view to show other node;
- CCK + nodereference field - show other node via spec.module;
- Taxonomy - set for these node concrete term and see via taxonomy/term/CONCRETE_TID;
- and more and more...
  Recommend to use views.

Comment: I like :: Custom node theming - programmatically call node_view to show other node; :: Do you have any tutorial or documentation links for this ? thank you

Comment: $second_node = node_load(YOUR_NODE_NID); print node_view($second_node, FALSE, true, false);

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) if you want to have multiple nodes/sections per page